# Differentiable round function in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So the output of my network is a list of propabilities, which I then round using tf.round() to be either 0 or 1, this is crucial for this project. 
I then found out that tf.round isn't differentiable so I'm kinda lost there.. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rounding is a fundamentally nondifferentiable function, so you're out of luck there. The normal procedure for this kind of situation is to find a way to either use the probabilities, say by using them to calculate an expected value, or by taking the maximum probability that is output and choose that one as the network's prediction. If you aren't using the output for calculating your loss function though, you can go ahead and just apply it to the result and it doesn't matter if it's differentiable. Now, if you want an informative loss function for the purpose of training the network, maybe you should consider whether keeping the output in the format of probabilities might actually be to your advantage (it will likely make your training process smoother)- that way you can just convert the probabilities to actual estimates outside of the network, after training.

Comment: My output has to be a value of 1 or 0. But because most of the outputs in the training data are 0 the network just learns to output mostly very low valueds from 0 - 0.0001 and I'm really kinda lost here. So I thought forcing it to output either a 1 or 0 would help.. I thought about just putting a 1 instead of where the derivative of the round function is supposed to be, but then again I use Tensorflow I can't decide the derivatives

Comment: In that case, the solution should be to oversample the data so that 50% is 1 and 50% is 0. Than it wouldn't matter, because you would eliminate the problem entirely by giving the same number of 0 and 1 on the output

Answer (score 23):

Something along the lines of x - sin(2pi x)/(2pi)?

I'm sure there's a way to squish the slope to be a bit steeper.

[image]

Comment: This is an underrated answer.  Sincerely, -someone who needed all reals; not just [0,1]

Comment: I agree this answer is very useful. When something is not possible, use approximation.

Comment: This idea is amazing, but in my code I tweaked it for slightly better differentiation properties: x/2 - sin(2pi x)/(4pi). It has the same basic shape, but the derivative at 0.5n = 1, so it should converge nicer. For reference, I did this by integrating (1 - cos(2pi))/2, which is a sine wave oscillating between 0 and 1

Comment: @ConsciousCode that's no longer an answer to the question since it's not "rounding" but "rounding and halving" -- though the scaling of the values and the derivatives would be taken care of at some point by any practical application so i don't think it matters either way

Answer (score 11):

You can use the fact that tf.maximum() and tf.minimum() are differentiable, and the inputs are probabilities from 0 to 1

```
# round numbers less than 0.5 to zero;
# by making them negative and taking the maximum with 0
differentiable_round = tf.maximum(x-0.499,0)
# scale the remaining numbers (0 to 0.5) to greater than 1
# the other half (zeros) is not affected by multiplication
differentiable_round = differentiable_round * 10000
# take the minimum with 1
differentiable_round = tf.minimum(differentiable_round, 1)
```

Example:

```
[0.1,       0.5,     0.7]
[-0.0989, 0.001, 0.20099] # x - 0.499
[0,       0.001, 0.20099] # max(x-0.499, 0)
[0,          10,  2009.9] # max(x-0.499, 0) * 10000
[0,         1.0,     1.0] # min(max(x-0.499, 0) * 10000, 1)
```

Comment: Cool answer! Though has anyone tried using this to train models? Sounds very complicated and I hope models can converge.

Comment: Now that I tried implementing it, I am not sure it will work. The issue about step function is not that we cannot represent it in tensorflow, but rather it is nondifferentiable. Finding a way to represent it using differentiable operator would still give you a nondifferentiable function.

Comment: Same here, I tried implementing this but the model's loss was constant. Seems the model can't converge with this kind of function.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
x_rounded_NOT_differentiable = tf.round(x)
x_rounded_differentiable = x - tf.stop_gradient(x - x_rounded_NOT_differentiable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on a previous answer, a way to get an arbitrarily good approximation is to approximate `round()` using a finite Fourier approximation and use as many terms as you need. Fundamentally, you can think of `round(x)` as adding a reverse (i. e. descending) sawtooth wave to `x`. So, using the Fourier expansion of the sawtooth wave we get

[image: round(x) ≈ x + 1/π ∑_n^N (-1)^n sin(2π n x)/n]

With *N* = 5, we get a pretty nice approximation:[image: plot of approximate round()]

Comment: It's certainly differentiable but the gradient is very non-monotonic so I'm not sure it's useful for most purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of an old question, but I just solved this problem for TensorFlow 2.0.  I am using the following round function on in my audio auto-encoder project.  I basically want to create a discrete representation of sound which is compressed in time.  I use the round function to clamp the output of the encoder to integer values.  It has been working well for me so far.

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def round_with_gradients(x):
    def grad(dy):
        return dy
    return tf.round(x), grad
```

Answer (score 1):

In tensorflow 2.10, there is a function called [`soft_round`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfc/ops/soft_round) which achieves exactly this.

Fortunately, for those who are using lower versions, the source code is really simple, so I just [copy-pasted those lines](https://github.com/tensorflow/compression/blob/50ad094cc5b276a58651c646692a97b8081bc8b2/tensorflow_compression/python/ops/round_ops.py#L46-L75), and it works like a charm:

```py
def soft_round(x, alpha, eps=1e-3):
    """Differentiable approximation to `round`.

    Larger alphas correspond to closer approximations of the round function.
    If alpha is close to zero, this function reduces to the identity.

    This is described in Sec. 4.1. in the paper
    > "Universally Quantized Neural Compression"<br />
    > Eirikur Agustsson & Lucas Theis<br />
    > https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.09952

    Args:
    x: `tf.Tensor`. Inputs to the rounding function.
    alpha: Float or `tf.Tensor`. Controls smoothness of the approximation.
    eps: Float. Threshold below which `soft_round` will return identity.

    Returns:
    `tf.Tensor`
    """
    # This guards the gradient of tf.where below against NaNs, while maintaining
    # correctness, as for alpha < eps the result is ignored.
    alpha_bounded = tf.maximum(alpha, eps)


    m = tf.floor(x) + .5
    r = x - m
    z = tf.tanh(alpha_bounded / 2.) * 2.
    y = m + tf.tanh(alpha_bounded * r) / z


    # For very low alphas, soft_round behaves like identity
    return tf.where(alpha < eps, x, y, name="soft_round")
```

`alpha` sets how soft the function is. Greater values leads to better approximations of round function, but then it becomes harder to fit since gradients vanish:

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.arange(-2,2,.1).astype(np.float32))

for alpha in [ 3., 7., 15.]:

    y = soft_round(x, alpha)
    plt.plot(x.numpy(), y.numpy(), label=f'alpha={alpha}')

plt.legend()
plt.title('Soft round function for different alphas')
plt.grid()
```

In my case, I tried different values for alpha, and 3. looks like a good choice.

[image: soft round function for different values of alpha]

Answer (score 0):

In range 0 1, translating and scaling a sigmoid can be a solution:

```
  slope = 1000
  center = 0.5
  e = tf.exp(slope*(x-center))
  round_diff = e/(e+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply approximate rounding (thus differentiable) using this function

```
def diff_round(x):
    return torch.round(x) + (x - torch.round(x))**3
```

Replace torch.round with diff_round