# Is there a differentiable way to cast a tensor into int64?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, casting, sparse-matrix, gradient

I'm creating a layer which uses its input tensors to create a SparseTensor, i.e., the input tensors are the respective indices and values of the SparseTensor.

Since:

> indices: A 2-D int64 tensor of shape

And because `tf.cast(x, tf.int64)` is not differentiable, I'm not sure if this is achievable.

Another option is to find a turnaround based on `tf.round()`, but SparseTensor won't accept a different type of tensor as indices.

Is there a way to cast a tensor to integer and not having `None` for gradient ?

How can I create a SparseTensor using previous layers outputs, which are float tensors ?

Comment: Any sort of rounding function would have a derivative of 0 almost everywhere.

Comment: @interjay Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596636/differentiable-round-function-in-tensorflow) could work, but SparseTensor construction class won't accept a `float32` tensor as indices