# How to calculate one hot encoding of a floating point value in a Keras graph

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Straight to the point, here's my Keras model:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, Input, backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

input_layer = Input(shape=(1,), name="input")

x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name="dense_1")(input_layer)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='softmax', name="dense_2")(x)

model = models.Model(input_layer, x)
model.summary()
```

Each input of the dataset is a floating-point number as well as the target. But the model generates a categorical value as the output which is the rasterization of the target. For instance, let's say the target is a number between 10 and 20. And I want to make it into a categorical value by dividing the range into 6 categories:

```
[10, 12) -> 0 -> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[12, 14) -> 1 -> [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[14, 16) -> 2 -> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[16, 18) -> 3 -> [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 20) -> 4 -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[20, 20] -> 5 -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I know I can preprocess the dataset and change all the targets into one-hot vectors and then feed them into my model. But for educational purposes, I would like to keep my targets as floating points and convert them into one-hot vectors within the model's pipeline.

For that, I wrote a custom loss function:

```py
def one_hot_loss(x, y):
    min = 10
    max = 20
    steps = 2
    num_classes = (max - min) / steps
    transformed = (y - min) / (max - min) * num_classes
    transformed_int = K.cast(transformed, "uint8")
    one_hot = tf.one_hot(transformed_int, depth=int(num_classes))
    return tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(x, one_hot)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=one_hot_loss)
```

In order to test this, I tried to call the `fit` method:

```py
model.fit([[1.0]], [[15.0]])
```

This faces the following error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
  (['dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0'],).
  Provided `grads_and_vars` is
    ((None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(1, 128) dtype=float32>),
    (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>),
    (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(128, 1024) dtype=float32>),
    (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_2/bias:0' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32>)).
```

My question is, why there was no gradient provided? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is `tf.cast` (or `K.cast`) is not differentiable. You could try to find some differentiable round function like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596636/differentiable-round-function-in-tensorflow."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596636/differentiable-round-function-in-tensorflow.%22)

Comment: Thanks. You are most likely right but the problem is that `tf.not_hot` accepts only int!