# How to build a model and train it with tensorflow keras sub classing

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I have written a custom Encoder and Decoder layers that implements the architecture described in the **Attention Is All You Need** paper. Everything works fine until I trying compiling it, I get one error. If I run it with a sample data it compiles but then when I call the `fit` method to train the model it throws another error. I'm going to provide the blocks that I might be implementing incorrectly and let me know if more code is needed to debug.

**TF Version: 2.14.0**

**Multi-Head Sub Layer and Positional Encoding Layer:**

```
class MhaSubLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    self.mha = MultiHeadAttention(key_dim=units, **kwargs)
    self.inner_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
    self.outer_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(units))
    self.layernorm_mha = LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm_ff = LayerNormalization()
    self.add = Add()

  def call(self, x, context, **kwargs):
    ### Calculate Attention Output
    attn_out, attn_scores = self.mha(query=x, value=context, return_attention_scores=True, **kwargs)

    attn_resid_cnxt = self.add([x, attn_out])  ## Residual connection
    attn_layer_norm = self.layernorm_mha(attn_resid_cnxt) 

    attn_scores = tf.reduce_mean(attn_scores, axis=1)
    self.last_attention_weights = attn_scores

    ### Pass the Attention output to the Dense Layer
    dense_out = self.outer_dense(self.inner_dense(attn_layer_norm))
    dense_resid_cnxt = self.add([attn_layer_norm, dense_out])  ### Feed forward residual connection

    dense_layer_norm = self.layernorm_ff(dense_resid_cnxt)
    return dense_layer_norm

class PositionalEncodingLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    self.add = Add()

  def get_positional_encodings(self, x):
    seq_len = x.shape[0]
    d = x.shape[1]
    
    P = np.zeros((seq_len, d))

    for k in range(seq_len):
        for i in np.arange(int(d/2)):
            denominator = np.power(10000, 2*i/d)
            P[k, 2*i] = np.sin(k/denominator)
            P[k, 2*i+1] = np.cos(k/denominator)
    return P
  
  def call(self, x):

    # pos_enc = []
    pos_enc = tf.map_fn(fn=self.get_positional_encodings, elems=x)

    # for n, elm in enumerate(x):
    #   p = self.get_positional_encodings(elm)
    #   pos_enc.append(p)
    
    # pos_enc = tf.convert_to_tensor(pos_enc)

    pos_embeddings = self.add([x, pos_enc])
    return pos_embeddings
```

**Encoder-Decoder Block:**

```
class Encoder(Layer):
  def __init__(self, units, embed_input_dim, name='encoder', **kwargs):
    super().__init__()

    ### Encoder Input Embedding and Layer
    self.embedding = Embedding(input_dim=embed_input_dim, output_dim=units, name='en_embed_layer')
    self.pos_embedding = PositionalEncodingLayer(name='en_positional_embed_layer')

    ### Encoder Multi-Head Self Attention Sub Layer
    self.mha_sub_layer1 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='en_mha_layer_1')
    self.mha_sub_layer2 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='en_mha_layer_2')
    self.mha_sub_layer3 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='en_mha_layer_3')
    self.mha_sub_layer4 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='en_mha_layer_4')
    self.mha_sub_layer5 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='en_mha_layer_5')
    self.mha_sub_layer6 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='en_mha_layer_6')

    ### Encoder MHA Dropout Layer
    self.dropout =  Dropout(rate=0.1, name='en_dropout_pos_enc')
    self.dropout1 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='en_dropout_layer1')
    self.dropout2 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='en_dropout_layer2')
    self.dropout3 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='en_dropout_layer3')
    self.dropout4 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='en_dropout_layer4')
    self.dropout5 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='en_dropout_layer5')
    self.dropout6 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='en_dropout_layer6')

  def call(self, x):
    embedding_output = self.embedding(x)

    positional_embedding = self.pos_embedding(embedding_output)
    postitional_embedding = self.dropout(positional_embedding)

    ### First MHa Sub-Layer
    sub_layer1_out = self.mha_sub_layer1(positional_embedding, positional_embedding)
    sub_layer1_out = self.dropout1(sub_layer1_out)

    ### Second MHa Sub-Layer
    sub_layer2_out = self.mha_sub_layer2(sub_layer1_out, sub_layer1_out)
    sub_layer2_out = self.dropout2(sub_layer2_out)

    ### Third MHa Sub-Layer
    sub_layer3_out = self.mha_sub_layer3(sub_layer2_out, sub_layer2_out)
    sub_layer3_out = self.dropout3(sub_layer3_out)

    ### Fourth MHa Sub-Layer
    sub_layer4_out = self.mha_sub_layer4(sub_layer3_out, sub_layer3_out)
    sub_layer4_out = self.dropout4(sub_layer4_out)

    ### Fifth MHa Sub-Layer
    sub_layer5_out = self.mha_sub_layer5(sub_layer4_out, sub_layer4_out)
    sub_layer5_out = self.dropout5(sub_layer5_out)

    ### Sixth MHa Sub-Layer
    sub_layer6_out = self.mha_sub_layer6(sub_layer5_out, sub_layer5_out)
    sub_layer6_out = self.dropout6(sub_layer6_out)

    return sub_layer6_out

class Decoder(Layer):
  def __init__(self, units, embed_input_dim, name='decoder', **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    ### Decoder Input Embedding Layer
    self.embedding = Embedding(input_dim=embed_input_dim, output_dim=units, name='de_embed_layer')
    self.pos_embedding = PositionalEncodingLayer(name='de_positional_embed_layer')

    ### Decoder Multi-Head Attention Sub Layer
    self.mha_sub_layer1 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_1')
    self.mha_sub_layer2 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_2')
    self.mha_sub_layer3 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_3')
    self.mha_sub_layer4 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_4')
    self.mha_sub_layer5 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_5')
    self.mha_sub_layer6 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_6')

    ### Decoder MHA Droput Layer
    self.dropout =  Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_pos_enc')
    self.dropout1 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer1')
    self.dropout2 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer2')
    self.dropout3 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer3')
    self.dropout4 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer4')
    self.dropout5 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer5')
    self.dropout6 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer6')

    ### Dense Output Layer
    self.output_dense_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(1), name="output_layer")

  def call(self, x, en_context):
    embedding_output = self.embedding(x)
    positional_embedding = self.pos_embedding(embedding_output)
    postitional_embedding = self.dropout(positional_embedding)

    ### First MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer1_out = self.mha_sub_layer1(positional_embedding, positional_embedding)
    sub_layer1_out = self.dropout1(sub_layer1_out)

    ### Second MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer2_out = self.mha_sub_layer2(sub_layer1_out, en_context)
    sub_layer2_out = self.dropout2(sub_layer2_out)

    ### Third MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer3_out = self.mha_sub_layer3(sub_layer2_out, en_context)
    sub_layer3_out = self.dropout3(sub_layer3_out)

    ### Fourth MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer4_out = self.mha_sub_layer4(sub_layer3_out, en_context)
    sub_layer4_out = self.dropout4(sub_layer4_out)

    ### Fifth MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer5_out = self.mha_sub_layer5(sub_layer4_out, en_context)
    sub_layer5_out = self.dropout5(sub_layer5_out)

    ### Sixth MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer6_out = self.mha_sub_layer6(sub_layer5_out, en_context)
    sub_layer6_out = self.dropout6(sub_layer6_out)

    ### Output Dense Layer
    output = self.output_dense_layer(sub_layer6_out)
    output = tf.round(tf.abs(output))
    return output
```

**Sample Data:**

```
np.random.seed(42)
trainX = np.random.randint(0, high=250, size=(5,12))
trainXt_in = np.random.randint(0, high=250, size=(5,3))
trainY = np.random.randint(0, high=250, size=(5,3,1))
```

**Modelling Block:**

```
Training shape: ((1616304, 12), (1616304, 3), (1616304, 3, 1))

## The Model Sub-Class

class Trxster(Model):
  def __init__(self, units, en_embed_dim, de_embed_dim, name='Trxster', **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    self.encoder = Encoder(units, en_embed_dim)
    self.decoder = Decoder(units, de_embed_dim)

  def call(self, inputs):
    context_vec, target_in = inputs
    context = self.encoder(context_vec)
    preds = self.decoder(target_in, context)
    return preds

forecastor = Trxster(hsize, embed_dim, embed_dim)
forecastor.build(((12, 1),(3, 1)))
forecastor.summary()
```

**Error-1:**

> TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: Dimension value
> must be integer or None or have an **index** method, got value '(12,
> 1)' with type '<class 'tuple'>'.

If run the model with an example:

```
hsize = 512
embed_dim = 268

forecastor = Trxster(hsize, embed_dim, embed_dim)
forecastor((trainX, trainXt_in))

Model: "trxster_11"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 encoder_13 (Encoder)        multiple                  63156224  
                                                                 
 decoder_13 (Decoder)        multiple                  63156737  
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 126312961 (481.85 MB)
Trainable params: 126312961 (481.85 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________

### Fit the Model
batch_size = 64
epochs = 100
steps = trainX.shape[0]//batch_size
warmup_steps = steps//25

class MyLRSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
  def __init__(self, d_model, warmup_steps):
    self.d_model = d_model
    self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps

  def __call__(self, step):
    step_num = step.numpy()
    self.lr = []

    denom = self.d_model**(-0.5)
    numer = min(step_num**(-0.5), step_num*(self.warmup_steps**(-1.5)))
    lrate = np.divide(numer, denom)
    self.lr.append(lrate)

    return lrate

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=MyLRSchedule(hsize, warmup_steps), beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98, epsilon=1e-8)

### Configure Trxster
checkpoint_filepath = './training_ckpt'

cb = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, 
                                        monitor='val_loss',
                                        restore_best_weights=True),
      tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                                        filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
                                        save_weights_only=True,
                                        monitor='val_loss',
                                        mode='min',
                                        verbose=1,
                                        save_best_only=True)]

loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(), tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()]

forecastor.compile(optimizer=opt,
                   loss='mean_squared_error',
                   metrics=['acc','mean_absolute_error'])

history = forecastor.fit((trainX, trainXt_in), trainY,
                          batch_size=batch_size,
                          steps_per_epoch=steps,
                          epochs=1,
                          validation_data=((valX, ValXt_in), valY),
                          callbacks=cb)
```

**Error-2:** Providing few lines of error trace:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
> (['trxster_11/encoder_13/en_embed_layer/embeddings:0',
> 'trxster_11/encoder_13/mha_sub_layer_157/en_mha_layer_1/query/kernel:0',
> 'trxster_11/encoder_13/mha_sub_layer_157/en_mha_layer_1/query/bias:0',
> 'trxster_11/encoder_13/mha_sub_layer_157/en_mha_layer_1/key/kernel:0',
> 'trxster_11/encoder_13/mha_sub_layer_157/en_mha_layer_1/key/bias:0',
> 'trxster_11/encoder_13/mha_sub_layer_157/en_mha_layer_1/value/kernel:0',
> 'trxster_11/encoder_13/mha_sub_layer_157/en_mha_layer_1/value/bias:0',
> 'trxster_11/encoder_13/mha_sub_layer_157/en_mha_layer_1/attention_output/kernel:0',
> 'trxster_11/encoder_13/mha_sub_layer_157/en_mha_layer_1/attention_output/bias:0',
> 'trxster_11/encoder_13/mha_sub_layer_157/time_distributed_314/kernel:0'

Every examples I see tells me that it should work just the way I have written but it isn't so.

Comment: Is it possible to provide full code that reproduce the issues? Add some dummy data as well.

Comment: Hi again @Innat! I have provided the full code along with the sample data. I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Gradient calculations fail when there is a tensorflow function in the graph which is the case in my network where I have applied `tf.round` and `tf.abs` in the output layer of the `Decoder`. That was failing the gradient calculations. I removed them and it the model trains as expected. Here is the link to the issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511.

**Decoder:**

```
class Decoder(Layer):
  def __init__(self, units, embed_input_dim, name='decoder', **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    ### Decoder Input Embedding Layer
    self.embedding = Embedding(input_dim=embed_input_dim, output_dim=units, name='de_embed_layer')
    self.pos_embedding = PositionalEncodingLayer(name='de_positional_embed_layer')

    ### Decoder Multi-Head Attention Sub Layer
    self.mha_sub_layer1 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_1')
    self.mha_sub_layer2 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_2')
    self.mha_sub_layer3 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_3')
    self.mha_sub_layer4 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_4')
    self.mha_sub_layer5 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_5')
    self.mha_sub_layer6 = MhaSubLayer(units, num_heads=8, name='de_mha_layer_6')

    ### Decoder MHA Droput Layer
    self.dropout =  Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_pos_enc')
    self.dropout1 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer1')
    self.dropout2 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer2')
    self.dropout3 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer3')
    self.dropout4 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer4')
    self.dropout5 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer5')
    self.dropout6 = Dropout(rate=0.1, name='de_dropout_layer6')

    ### Dense Output Layer
    self.output_dense_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(1), name="output_layer")

  def call(self, x, en_context):
    embedding_output = self.embedding(x)
    positional_embedding = self.pos_embedding(embedding_output)
    postitional_embedding = self.dropout(positional_embedding)

    ### First MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer1_out = self.mha_sub_layer1(positional_embedding, positional_embedding)
    sub_layer1_out = self.dropout1(sub_layer1_out)

    ### Second MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer2_out = self.mha_sub_layer2(sub_layer1_out, en_context)
    sub_layer2_out = self.dropout2(sub_layer2_out)

    ### Third MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer3_out = self.mha_sub_layer3(sub_layer2_out, en_context)
    sub_layer3_out = self.dropout3(sub_layer3_out)

    ### Fourth MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer4_out = self.mha_sub_layer4(sub_layer3_out, en_context)
    sub_layer4_out = self.dropout4(sub_layer4_out)

    ### Fifth MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer5_out = self.mha_sub_layer5(sub_layer4_out, en_context)
    sub_layer5_out = self.dropout5(sub_layer5_out)

    ### Sixth MHA Sub-Layer
    sub_layer6_out = self.mha_sub_layer6(sub_layer5_out, en_context)
    sub_layer6_out = self.dropout6(sub_layer6_out)

    ### Output Dense Layer
    output = self.output_dense_layer(sub_layer6_out)
    return output
```

Comment: nice findings, upvoted. Here is some [pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008500/9215780) if you like to use rounding anyway. Also, in your PositionalEncodingLayer layer, you're calling np inside the call method. Instead, use `build` method to construct `P`. In the build method, you can safely use np methods. Thus no need tf.map_fn or any other hacks. It's safer.

Comment: Thanks, Innat. That is a good suggestion!